# php handling < file input from command line

Tags: php, command-line-interface, stdin

I know that I can receive args on a command line/shell script like this:

```
!#/usr/bin/php
<?php
# file name - process.php
print_r($argv);
```

But what about redirects as follows:

```
#> ./process.php < input.txt
```

How do I read the file, and is `input.txt` a string argument or some type of file pointer already created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Read from STDIN](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php) very similar to C:

```
<?php
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
// Get the whole file, line by line:
while (($line = fgets($stdin)) !== FALSE) {
    ...
}
?>
```

If you'd rather get the whole file contents into one variable, there's a shortcut:

```
$contents = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
```

Comment: very concise answer.  BTW: What is the `<` character referred to (and `>`) in shell scripting?

Comment: It doesn't have a specific name afaik but < and > are referred to as redirection operators.

Comment: Also, I am getting the MIME type echoed to STDOUT (regardless of whether I have any coding in the script or not).  I.e. `Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` - how do I suppress this?

Comment: @OliverWilliams Something in your script (or maybe a library) is setting an HTTP header.  To suppress header output on the CLI run PHP with `php -h`.

Comment: Matt I edited-suggested your answer, the hash-bang should look like `#!/usr/bin/php -q` to suppress this.  Wild guess -q stands for quiet ;)

Answer (score 1):

Oliver, instead of modifying a user's post, you should post a different answer. Here is what you intended to post:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
    //NOTE the -q switch in hashbang above, silences MIME type output when reading the file!
    $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
    // Get the whole file, line by line:
    while (($line = fgets($stdin)) !== FALSE) {
        ...
    }
?>
```